Best way to remove gaps on candlestick chart using JS Observable Plot (d3)?
I have been working on a candlestick chart using Observable Plot, and I have come across a problem with gaps in the chart. In my dataset, there are of course gaps for weekends when no trading occurs, but I did not expect these gaps to appear in the final plot. This is my first time using Observable Plot.
const ticker = parseDates(tickerData);
const radioBtns = document.getElementsByName("chartType");
let chartType;

for(var i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++) {
  radioBtns[i].onclick = updateChart;
}

updateChart();

function updateChart() {
  // reset images
  candlestickLabel.childNodes[0].src = "assets/candlestick-unselected.png";
  lineLabel.childNodes[0].src = "assets/line-unselected.png";
  areaLabel.childNodes[0].src = "assets/area-unselected.png";

  for (let i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++) {
    // loop through radio buttons
    if (radioBtns[i].checked) {
      // set chartType to the value of the selected button
      chartType = radioBtns[i];
      
      // loop through labels and set the image to selected if checked
      const labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
      for (let j = 0; j < labels.length; j++) {
        if (labels[j].htmlFor == radioBtns[i].id) {
          labels[j].childNodes[0].src = "assets/" + chartType.value + "-selected.png";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // set up chart based on selected type
  let plot = null;

  if (chartType.value == "candlestick") {plot = Plot.plot({
      inset: 20,
      width: 1000,
      height: 400,
      grid: true,
      x: {
        domain: [ticker[0].date, ticker[ticker.length - 1].date],
        reverse: true,
        tickFormat: d => Plot.formatIsoDate(d), // Format ticks as dates
        tickRotate: -15,
        tickPadding: 5,
      },
      y: {
        label: "↑ Stock price ($)"
      },
      color: {
        domain: [-1, 0, 1],
        range: ["#f23645", "currentColor", "#138808"]
      },
      marks: [
        Plot.ruleX(ticker.filter(d => d.low), {
          x: "date",
          y1: "low",
          y2: "high",
          stroke: d => Math.sign(d.close - d.open),
        }),
        Plot.ruleX(ticker, {
          x: "date",
          y1: "open",
          y2: "close",
          stroke: d => Math.sign(d.close - d.open),
          strokeWidth: 4,
          strokeLinecap: "butt"
        })
      ]
    });
  } else if (chartType.value == "line") {
    plot = Plot.plot({
      inset: 6,
      // width and height match that of container
      width: 1000,
      height: 400,
      grid: true,
      x: {
        // set the domain
        domain: [new Date(ticker[0].date), new Date(ticker[ticker.length - 1].date)],
        reverse: true
      },
      y: {
        label: "↑ Stock Price ($)"
      },
      marks: [
        Plot.lineY(ticker, {
          x: "date",
          y: "close",
          stroke: "#6495ed"
        })
      ]
    });
  } else {
    plot = Plot.plot({
      inset: 6,
      // width and height match that of container
      width: 1000,
      height: 400,
      grid: true,
      x: {
        // set the domain
        domain: [new Date(ticker[0].date), new Date(ticker[ticker.length - 1].date)],
        reverse: true
      },
      y: {
        label: "↑ Stock Price ($)"
      },
      marks: [
        Plot.lineY(ticker, {
          x: "date",
          y: "close",
          stroke: "#6495ed"
        }),
        Plot.areaY(ticker, {
          x: "date",
          y1: Math.min(...ticker.map((t) => t.close)) - 10,
          y2: "close",
          fill: "#6495ed",
          fillOpacity: 0.3
        })
      ]
    });
  }

  const div = chartDiv;
  div.innerHTML = "";
  div.append(plot);
}

// UTILITY FUNCTIONS

const weeks = (start, stop, stride) => d3.utcMonday.every(stride).range(start, +stop + 1);
const weekdays = (start, stop) => d3.utcDays(start, +stop + 1).filter(d => d.getUTCDay() !== 0 && d.getUTCDay() !== 6);

function parseDates(data) {
  return data.map(d => ({
    ...d,
    date: new Date(d.date)  // Ensure `date` is a Date object
  }));
}

Here is my dataset format:
const tickerData = [{
          date: "2024-09-10",
          open: 204.2000,
          high: 205.8300,
          low: 202.8700,
          close: 205.3200,
          volume: 3070644
        },{
          date: "2024-09-09",
          open: 201.9400,
          high: 205.0500,
          low: 201.4300,
          close: 203.5300,
          volume: 3705004
        },{
          date: "2024-09-06",
          open: 202.3800,
          high: 204.1000,
          low: 199.3350,
          close: 200.7400,
          volume: 3304491
        }
}]

I have tried several solutions, but to no avail. First I made sure that the dataset was parsed correctly and contained no weekend data. I have also tried several things using the tick, tickFormat, and domain options for the x-axis.

Have you seen this example?



// sample data
    const tickerData = [
      { date: "2024-09-10", open: 204.2, high: 205.83, low: 202.87, close: 205.32, volume: 3070644 },
      { date: "2024-09-09", open: 201.94, high: 205.05, low: 201.43, close: 203.53, volume: 3705004 },
      { date: "2024-09-06", open: 202.38, high: 204.1, low: 199.34, close: 200.74, volume: 3304491 },
      { date: "2024-09-05", open: 200.5, high: 202.75, low: 198.5, close: 200.2, volume: 3100000 },
      { date: "2024-09-04", open: 198.4, high: 201.6, low: 197.8, close: 200.0, volume: 2900000 },
      { date: "2024-09-03", open: 195.6, high: 199.9, low: 195.0, close: 198.4, volume: 2800000 },
      { date: "2024-08-30", open: 196.2, high: 197.8, low: 194.6, close: 196.4, volume: 2600000 },
      { date: "2024-08-29", open: 198.0, high: 199.5, low: 195.8, close: 196.8, volume: 2700000 },
      { date: "2024-08-28", open: 197.5, high: 200.0, low: 196.0, close: 198.9, volume: 2500000 },
      { date: "2024-08-27", open: 199.0, high: 200.4, low: 197.5, close: 198.3, volume: 2400000 },
      { date: "2024-08-26", open: 198.2, high: 199.9, low: 195.6, close: 196.5, volume: 2300000 }
    ];

    // parse dates to Date objects
    function parseDates(data) {
      return data.map(d => ({
        ...d,
        date: new Date(d.date)
      }));
    }

    // filter out weekends (non-trading days) 
    // better to send only trading day data 
    function filterTradingDates(data) {
      return data.filter(d => d.date.getUTCDay() !== 0 && d.date.getUTCDay() !== 6); // Exclude Sundays (0) and Saturdays (6)
    }

    // filtered and parsed data
    const ticker = filterTradingDates(parseDates(tickerData));


    function createChart(data) {
      const plot = Plot.plot({
        inset: 20,
        width: 1000,
        height: 400,
        grid: true,
        x: {
          type: "band", // Note : use an ordinal scale for even spacing 
          domain: data.map(d => d.date),
          tickFormat: d3.utcFormat("%Y-%m-%d"), 
          tickRotate: -15,
          tickPadding: 5,
        },
        y: {
          label: "↑ Stock Price ($)"
        },
        color: {
          domain: [-1, 0, 1],
          range: ["#f23645", "currentColor", "#138808"]
        },
        marks: [
          Plot.ruleX(data, {
            x: "date",
            y1: "low",
            y2: "high",
            stroke: d => Math.sign(d.close - d.open),
          }),
          
          Plot.ruleX(data, {
            x: "date",
            y1: "open",
            y2: "close",
            stroke: d => Math.sign(d.close - d.open),
            strokeWidth: 4,
            strokeLinecap: "butt"
          })
        ]
      });

      const div = document.getElementById("chartDiv");
      div.innerHTML = ""; 
      div.append(plot);
    }

    createChart(ticker);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/plot@0.6"></script>
<div id="chartDiv" style="width: 1000px; height: 400px;"></div>



